# How to upgrade to EntLib 5 (from 1.1) IRolesProvider doesn't exist

Tags: enterprise-library

We are upgrading from enterprise lib 1.1 to 5.0, where some of the Interface and class are not for in enterprise lib 5.0 dll reference.

1. ConfigurationProvider
2. IRolesProvider
3. SecurityConfigurationView

These are not working in enterprise library 5.0

Answer (score 0):

1. Configuration was moved into .NET 2.0 so any custom configuration should be converted to use the BCL classes.
2. I would think that IRolesProvider would be replaced with the abstract [RoleProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.roleprovider.aspx) class.
3. SecurityConfigurationView was removed between version 4.1 and version 5.0.  It's just a small facade over the SecuritySettings configuration class.  You could either access the SecuritySettings directly or (re)create the functionality with your own class.